# Why does a continuous tense verb not take '-times' word?

Tags: present-continuous

What is the problem with 'I'm jumping twice'? I don't understand why it is wrong...

Comment: Could you please add more reference to the context? Like where you saw this phrase in use. In simple words, source of the whole sentence.

Comment: The continuous tense means that you are doing the action continuously! If you jump twice, presumably you stop after the second time. (This isn't a complete answer, I know. 'I'm jumping twice' could be a valid sentence meaning 'I intend to jump twice'.)

Comment: *He's making a list, he's checking it twice*... Your usage feels off because the present continuous tense in its base usage describes what you're doing at this specific moment, and it's not really possible to eg. jump twice *at the same point in time*. But other uses of Present Continuous, or loosening the definition of a "specific moment" can allow this construction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only context that comes to mind is this...

I'm Bungee jumping and the instructor says to me:"Sorry mate, you can only jump once", Informally I would reply, "no, I'm jumping twice!", I do not know if it's grammatically correct but I believe it is possible.

Comment: Yes, it can be a valid usage, as I noted in my comment above.